# /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by ./bomb)

Tags: glibc

I have got the executable bomb, but this error is preventing me to execute it. Please help!!!

I tried installing glibc 2.31 (which was successful). But the error still exists.

Answer (score 3):

The error means: `./bomb` binary was built on and *requires* GLIBC-2.34 or newer.

> I tried installing glibc 2.31 (which was successful). But the error still exists.

GLIBC-2.31 is not "2.34 or newer", what did you expect?

Your best bet is to install `docker` image with GLIBC-2.34 (or newer) and run the binary in that `docker` container.

It is possible to install GLIBC-2.34 into an alternate location without using `docker`, but any mistakes you make could render your system un-bootable, so I don't recommend this approach.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617).